# Write an .htaccess rewrite rule excluding one file

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

I'm working with a framework and need to make a call to a specific file within a directory, however the directory is set up for url of all requests to index.php for the framework's sake.

I have a file called `check-session.php` and need any requests to `localhost/admin/check-session.php` to execute the actual check-session.php file instead of route to `index.php`. How do I do that with .htaccess file within the same folder as `check-session.php`?

I have little to no experience with rewrite rules / conditions.

Comment: Please post your existing .htaccess from `$DOCUMENT_ROOT/admin` directory.

Comment: Add `RewriteRule ^admin/check-session\.php$ - [L]` above the catch-all rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the RewriteRule that rewrites to index.php and put these directly before it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
```

That should stop it mapping to index.php if it's a real file you request.

If that doesn't work, post the actual rewrites in .htaccess

Comment: Not working, this is how it's setup.

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php

Comment: That's the full extent of the .htaccess file?

Comment: Try adding: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ I've added it to my answer.